# How to study the continuity of a function on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: analysis, continuity

I'm trying to study the continuity of this function on $\Bbb R$

$$f(x)=\sin (x) \cdot[x]$$

Where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

I know that in order to study continuity I need to see if the image of $x$ by $f$ in all points $a$ of $\Bbb R$ is equal to $\lim \limits_{x \to a}f(x)$. However I think this interval is too big, and I don't know how I should exactly *approach* this kind of problem.

Should I break the interval $\Bbb R$ into parts? How do I know exactly which parts?

Thank you.

Comment: In general, it is good to come up with some collection of points that you suspect might be discontinuities based on what you know about the functions. If $[x]$ is meant to denote floor, or ceiling, or any other kind of rounding function, then the integers are a natural starting place to look.

Comment: do you simply mean x(sin x)? sin x [x] is a bit unconventional. I'll get to work on proving x(sin x), unless you give me additional info otherwise.

Comment: wait, the integer part. I get it. sorry. I definitely agree with what Jean-Claude Arbaut just said. There is a jump at each integer.

Comment: @AdamV.Nease no I mean sin(x).[x] , [x] being the integer part of x.

Comment: I understand now. I'll work on the proof with this in mind, unless someone else finishes it first.

Comment: okay thank you  @AdamV.Nease I'm working on it too

Comment: wait how can I start with x=1 if the sine function only takes numbers with pi in them?

Comment: 1=(1/pi)pi. So that's how. Also, does the question say prove prove that it's not continuous, or not continuous *everywhere*?

Comment: The approaches I'd take are different for each case. so that's important.

Comment: the question only says "study the continuity of f on R" it doesn't precise whether it's continuous or not.

Comment: doesn't matter. I just realized there are plenty of points where it is continuous. It's just not continuous over every single point in its domain. There's $\aleph_0$ points of discontinuity.

Comment: I'm making some progress by the way, although I hope I'm not speaking too soon.

Comment: f(-x) = f(x) so the function is even. we can study it only on R+ and conclude it on R-  right?

Comment: there are points where it's continuous and points where it's not continuous. Basically, if we study the function over any interval between two integers, it's continuous because all of the points u in the interval are accumulation points and you can prove the limit exists by proving limx->u exists, and it will be easy, because the formula for f(x) will only be ceiling(u)sin (x) and thus the limit as x approaches u will be ceiling(u)sin (u), since the ceiling of u will be a constant.

Comment: i'm now working on proving it's discontinuous at each integer.

Comment: you could study it on R^+, but there's not really any need; but that definitely works, i think.

Comment: wait. got it. I'm typing the solution below as an answer now. Hang tight for about 10-12 minutes. I'll try not to use too much Latex so it shortens the typing time.

Comment: Actually, that was a good idea to break it into R+ R- because the integer part is the floor in R+ and ceiling in R-. that changes my argument avove slightly, but it's the same idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to see the result: Let $[x]$ denote the floor function.

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x)=\sin(x) [x]$.

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Suppose that $x$ is not an integer, so it is somewhere in $(n,n+1)$ for some integer $n$. for each sufficiently small neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we know that $f\vert_{U}=n\cdot \sin \vert_{U}.$ Since
$\sin$ is continuous,  so is $(n \cdot \sin)$.

To see why $\sin$ is continuous: [How to prove a function is always continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882526/how-to-prove-a-function-is-always-continuous/1882534#1882534])

Now, suppose that $x$ is an integer $n$. Consider the little interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. On the left side, we see that $f \vert_{(x-\epsilon,x)}=(n-1)\sin$ while $f \vert_{(x+\epsilon)}=n \sin$.

But $$\lim_{y \to x} (n-1) \sin(x)=(n-1)\lim_{y\to x} \sin(x) \neq n\cdot \lim_{y \to x} \sin(x)=\lim_{y \to x} n \sin(x).$$

Since the left and right limits are different, we can conclude that $f$ is discontinuous on any integer.

Comment: i didn't understand this part: lim n = (n−1)sin(x) = (n−1) lim sin(x)
can you please clarify it? (I mean how does "lim n" equal that? isn't **_n_** an integer?)

Comment: @MariemElMajdoubi that was a typo. Nice catch.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the 4th line too:  _f|=n⋅sin|UU_

Comment: Seems correct to me, it's just the restriction onto $U $.

Comment: Okay, just one question: what about the case of x=0? we have lim f(0) = f(0) so it is continuous at 0 right?

Comment: No, I believe that it is standard for the floor of some number less than zero to still be the integer less than it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions